# Cannot enable interactive widnows using ssh -X when connecting to a Linux server from my Windows machine

Tags: linux, ssh, x11-forwarding, xming

I need some help. I am trying to use `ssh -X` to connect to a remote server that has enabled X11 forwarding.

When I use my MacBook to connect to the remote server, I use `ssh -X USERNAME@SERVER` and then if for example I type `matlab`, it opens the XQuartz application on my MacBook and then the GUI of matlab opens. Perfect until here.

I now want to do the same but from a Windows machine. I first start the Xming program. I can see it at the bottom right corner running (I see `Xming Serve:0.0`). When I repeat the above process, the matlab GUI does not open.

I also tried to connect using `ssh -v -X` and after inserting my password I see this message among a lot:

> debug1: X11 forwarding requested but DISPLAY not set

I tried to run (on my local terminal before ssh attempt): `SET DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` and then `echo %DISPLAY%` returns `localhost:0.0` but still `ssh -X` still does not open GUIs.

What is localhost and where can I find it?
Any help?

**EDIT:**

Managed to solve this after being inspired by the comments.

Step 1: I right-clicked xming and opened its log. In there, I found an IP for the DISPLAY.

Step 2: `export` does not exist on Windows so I used `SET DISPLAY=IP:0.0`

Step 3: `ssh -X` failed again but `ssh -Y` worked!!!

Comment: I can only speak to the last thing you tried and tell you how >I< do it.  Setting the display on your local terminal in windows is *pointless*.  You are setting the variable on the REMOTE HOST, not windows.  I believe that ssh -X does just that (but never used it via windows).    SSH into the remote.  export your display using the IP of the windows box.  let 'er rip.. as in `xterm &` (or whatever).  Also, I think VcXsrv is better than Xming.  Get simple ssh THEN forwarding to work.. then jump into the ssh -X command.

Comment: export your display using the IP of the windows box.. as in log into your remote via ssh.. then `export DISPLAY=<windows_ip_here>:0.0`.  If you get that working, you will at least know the mechanism is working.

Comment: Thanks both. I managed to solve the problem. I edited my post.

Comment: "export does not exist on Windows so I used SET DISPLAY=IP:0.0".  This did nothing.  You set the display on the machine PROVIDING x11, not the client.  It worked because your ssh command setup the remote environment for you.  And I am glad that you got it working :)

Comment: Hi. If I do not do this then the GUI does not work. So, no idea why but if I use `SET` before my ssh, GUIs work.

Comment: It worked for me too. I know DISPLAY on Windows shouldn't  affect the connection but it does. I observed that after connecting with `ssh -Y` the DISPLAY variable in Linux is already set to `localhost:10.0` and when I connect with `ssh -X`, it's not. But even if I set it manually, then X11 forwarding doesn't work.